# Atlassian Connector for Eclipse can't login to Jira

Tags: eclipse, jira, mylyn

Since today the Atlassian Connector can't login to our Jira installation. It's hosted at atlassian.net.

I can only see this Exception in the eclipse.log:

```
com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.internal.jira.core.service.JiraAuthenticationException: Client response status: 401
    at com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.internal.jira.core.service.rest.JiraRestClientAdapter.call(JiraRestClientAdapter.java:749)
    at com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.internal.jira.core.service.rest.JiraRestClientAdapter.getFavouriteFilters(JiraRestClientAdapter.java:274)
    at com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.internal.jira.core.service.JiraClient.getNamedFilters(JiraClient.java:562)
    at com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.internal.jira.ui.wizards.JiraNamedFilterPage$14.run(JiraNamedFilterPage.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
```

The Login on the website works without problem.

Does this problem relate to the [Hack on HipChat/Confluence](https://blog.hipchat.com/2017/04/24/hipchat-security-notice/)?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing Error 401 which is related to invalid authentication. Have you changed your password after incident? If so - check your [settings](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/IDEPLUGIN/Configuring+your+JIRA+Options+in+Eclipse) in Eclipse.

Comment: The credentials never changed: Yesterday it worked without problems. Today I started my eclipse and the error occured.

After resetting the password (and changed the credentials in eclipse) the error is still present. The login on the website still works with the new credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Next day it works again. Maybe fixed by atlassian.

thx anyways.